# SQL não retorna nenhum dado da tabela apesar de não dar erros

Tags: php, html, sql, aplicação-web

Bom dia, eu quero que no seguinte código o SQL retorna da base de dados os valores "id_Admin", "username_Admin", "password_Admin", mas não retorna nada apesar de não dar quaisquer erros.

```
<?php 

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "aeac";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    // Check c﻿onnection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("connection failed: "
            . mysqli_connect_error()
            . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
            . ")");
    }

    //get results from database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM admin");

    echo "<table id='tableId' align='center' style='width:60%; height:5%'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nome</﻿th>
    <th>Password</th>
    </tr>";

    while ($property = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td onclick='redirect()'>" . $property['id_Admin'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td onclick='redirect()'>" . $property['username_Admin'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td onclick='redirect()'>" . $property['password_Admin'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Já fiz várias pesquisas e troquei várias vezes o código para ver se algo funcionava mas nada. Tenho a certeza que todos os campos estão iguais aos da base de dados.

Desde já obrigado, RedCandy.﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um teste aqui, usando exatamente seu código e de fato não retornava nenhum erro, mas só consegui imprimir os resultados de acordo com o desejado da seguinte forma:

```
while($property = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Ou

```
while($property = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Pois só assim foi gerado um array associativo para imprimir os resultados.

> [mysqli_fetch_array() - ver sobre **result type**](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
>
> [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)